# Issue when retrieving records with empty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, arel

I have a table of around 100 Users and I also have an array of user ids. What I wanted to do is show all users who are not a part of this array of user ids. When I do something like this

```
 User.where('id NOT IN (?)', [9, 2, 3, 4])
```

It successfully returns the records where the user's id does not belong in that array. However if that array is empty like so

```
 User.where('id NOT IN (?)', [])
```

It does not return any users back and the SQL query looks like this

```
 SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (id NOT IN (NULL))
```

Does anyone know why this happens or could this be a bug? I am using Rails 3.2.5 with PostgreSQL.

Comment: That looks like a Rails issue or possibly a `Pg` gem issue; it's treating an empty array as `NULL`. Very odd - and bad behavour. Can you test a prepared statement with the `Pg` gem directly to see if it treats array parameters that way or if it's the Rails/ActiveRecord level doing it?

Comment: @CraigRinger: It'll be a Rails/ActiveRecord problem not a `pg` problem. AR handles the placeholders itself.

Comment: @CraigRinger: The AR people are surprising bad at SQL sometimes, they're doing this on purpose. Insert "son, I am disappoint" image here.

Comment: @muistooshort Yeah, it's not a tool I'd choose. Then again Hibernate (at least as popular) has its own share of exciting quirks, like defaulting to ignoring the `DEFAULT nextval(...)` of a serial column and instead generating IDs from its own `hibernate_sequence` shared across all tables. Woo! With AR handing its own placeholders I can't help but wonder about SQL injection and security, though; it doesn't seem ... super robust.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

ActiveRecord (3.2.1 at least) treats empty arrays as NULLs. The placeholders in a `where` call are handled by [`sanitize_sql`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-rel/activerecord/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb#L33). If you trace through the code for a bit, you'll come to [`replace_bind_variables`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-rel/activerecord/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb#L127):

```
def replace_bind_variables(statement, values) #:nodoc:
  raise_if_bind_arity_mismatch(statement, statement.count('?'), values.size)
  bound = values.dup
  c = connection
  statement.gsub('?') { quote_bound_value(bound.shift, c) }
end
```

and then [`quote_bound_value`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-rel/activerecord/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb#L163):

```
def quote_bound_value(value, c = connection) #:nodoc:
  if value.respond_to?(:map) && !value.acts_like?(:string)
    if value.respond_to?(:empty?) && value.empty?
      c.quote(nil)
    else
      value.map { |v| c.quote(v) }.join(',')
    end
  else
    c.quote(value)
  end
end
```

An empty Array will satisfy all four conditions to get you to `c.quote(nil)` and that's where your NULL comes from. All the special logic that leads to `c.quote(nil)` indicates that this is intentional behavior.

Saying IN (or NOT IN) with an empty list:

```
where c in ()
```

should produce an SQL error so maybe the AR people are trying to prevent that by quietly turning that bad SQL into `c in (null)`. Note that neither of these:

```
select ... from t where c in (null);
select ... from t where c not in (null);
```

should ever produce any results due to the behavior of SQL's NULL. This is a classic newbie mistake and the AR people really should know better.

I'd prefer an exception myself: telling me that I'm about to deploy a foot-bullet would be much friendlier than just handing me a different gun.

---

**Executive summary**:

1. This "empty array means NULL" behavior is intentional.
2. You should never ever try `where('c in (?)', [])` or `where('c not in (?)', [])` since neither statement makes much sense.
3. Update your Ruby code to check for empty arrays and do whatever needs to be done to get the results you expect.

Comment: Yep, the sane thing would *certainly* be an exception here.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I, as usual, blame MySQL :)

Comment: I understood now why my tests are failing. :)

Comment: I disagree with wanting an exception. If I want scope that just-works whether I pass an empty array or not, it's more elegant to construct an AR scope where I don't have to do empty array guards.

Comment: @gabe You're welcome to disagree but "just works" is often a short cut to hidden bugs, I'd strongly prefer a tool that tells me to make sense over one that tries to make sense of nonsense and silently does the wrong thing.

Comment: I agree the magic can cause side-effects but in the case I stumbled on this SO thread, I was intentionally passing an empty array as a default value for a scope (not accidentally). I guess I would agree with an exception as long as the exception told you to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/40155467/34315.

Answer (score 33):

In Rails 4 you can use `User.where.not(id: [])` which will give you the correct result. It produces:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (1 = 1)
```

Unfortunately `User.where('id NOT IN (?)', [])` should be equivalent but it is not. It still gives you the wrong result:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (id NOT IN (NULL))
```

References:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/778
- https://github.com/rails/arel/commit/cbff1bcf
- https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8332
- https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8d02afeaee8993bd0fde69687fdd9bf30921e805

Comment: On a vaguely related note, User.where(:id => [[], [3]]) gives you invalid sql: "SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` IN (, 3)"

Answer (score 9):

```
User.where('id NOT IN (?)', ids+[0])
```

Comment: Please consider adding a clarifying comment as to ***why*** this might be the correct answer.

Comment: @DavidL: This ensures that the array will not be empty. This also presumes that there is no id with value = 0 (in Rails it is often the case).

Answer (score 2):

Use ruby's active record wrapper:

```
User.where.not(id: [])
```

This handles the empty array issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the problem asked for, but I came here to find all records with an empty (serialized) array attribute. I solved it for Rails 5.0 like this:

```
User.where(my_array_attribute: nil)
```

Or for the inverse:

```
User.where.not(my_array_attribute: nil)
```