# Active Record NOT IN queries and NULL with MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a query like:

```
Tag.where('id not IN (?)', current_user.tags.pluck(:id)).uniq
```

When

```
current_user.tags.pluck(:id)).uniq
```

returns NULL, I get no results from the Tag query which isn't the desired behavior.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `current_user.tags.pluck(:id)` is returning you a `nil`, it is returning an empty array. [ActiveRecord will treat an empty array as a NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12946338/479863) in that context. The result is some nonsensical SQL like this:

```
select tags.* from tags where id in (null)
```

Due to the idiosyncrasies of SQL's NULL (in particular `x = NULL` and `x != NULL` are both false for all `x`), an `in (null)` or `not in (null)` in a WHERE clause won't match anything.

Rails converting Ruby's `[]` to `NULL` is pretty stupid (more discussion on that [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12946338/479863)) but even if it was smart enough to raise an exception, you'd still have to deal with the "empty array" case manually with something like this:

```
tag_ids = current_user.tags.pluck(:id)
if(tag_ids.empty?)
  tags = Tag.all
else
  tags = Tag.where('id not in (?)', tag_ids)
end
```

And you don't need the `uniq` in there, the SQL `in` operator will treat its RHS as a set so duplicates will be collapsed behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `where.not` to let Rails handle when the passed argument is an empty Array.

As *mu is too short* pointed out, when the passed value to the query condition is an empty Array, ActiveRecord turns that into `NULL` which messes up your query and will always return an empty result.

The old way of dealing with this is by conditionally check for an empty Array as the argument and not adding this condition. However, with Rails 4 that introduced `where.not`, we no longer have to have this check.

We can simply do:

```
Tag.where.not( id: current_user.tags.pluck(:id) ).uniq
```

And now ActiveRecord will automatically check for an empty Array and when it sees it, the condition becomes `1=1`, which essentially is meaningless but more importantly, it just gets ignored and the rest of your query will run as if that condition was never added to the query.

Comment: Don't even need to pluck the id :D

Comment: @MikeHeft Really? Rails must automatically return the primary key? I've never tried that, likely because we primarily use unique IDs but that's pretty clever if it works.

Comment: Ya, it's smart enough to know from the objects to get the id. Only works on the id column tho. For any other column, you'd need the pluck. :D

Comment: @MikeHeft Beauty! Thanks for confirming. Feel free to edit the answer if you like.