# What is the difference between using ? and % when sanitizing fields in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2, sanitize

I've been puzzled for a while over the difference between using a question mark, e.g.

```
Foo.find(:all, :conditions => ['bar IN (?)', @dangerous])
```

and using sprintf style field types, e.g.

```
Bar.find(:all, :conditions => ['qux IN (%s)', @dangerous])
```

in sanitizing inputs. Is there any security advantage whatsoever, if you know you're looking for a number - like an ID - and not a string, in using %d over ?, or are you just asking for a Big Nasty Error when a string comes along instead?

Does this change at all with the newer .where syntax in Rails 3 and 4?

Comment: i did not even know that this is possible in rails2

Comment: @muistooshort, it seems it works at least in Rails 3. Good point about future proofing since it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Comment: In 3+ I'd say `where(:bar => @dangerous)` anyway, that will do The Right Thing if `@dangerous` is a non-empty array (but alas, [something stupid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12946338/479863) if it is an empty array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%s` is intended for strings. The main difference is that `%s` doesn't add quotes. From [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods.where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where):

> Lastly, you can use sprintf-style % escapes in the template. This
>   works slightly differently than the previous methods; you are
>   responsible for ensuring that the values in the template are properly
>   quoted. The values are passed to the connector for quoting, but the
>   caller is responsible for ensuring they are enclosed in quotes in the
>   resulting SQL. After quoting, the values are inserted using the same
>   escapes as the Ruby core method `Kernel::sprintf`.

**Examples:**

```
User.where(["name = ? and email = ?", "Joe", "joe@example.com"])
# SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'Joe' AND email = 'joe@example.com';

User.where(["name = '%s' and email = '%s'", "Joe", "joe@example.com"])
# SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'Joe' AND email = 'joe@example.com';
```

*Update:*

You are passing an array. `%s` seems to calls `.to_s` on the argument so this might not works as expected:

```
User.where("name IN (%s)", ["foo", "bar"])
# SELECT * FROM users WHERE (name IN ([\"foo\", \"bar\"]))

User.where("name IN (?)", ["foo", "bar"])
# SELECT * FROM users WHERE (name IN ('foo','bar'))
```

For simple queries you can use the hash notation:

```
User.where(name: ["foo", "bar"])
# SELECT * FROM users WHERE name IN ('foo', 'bar')
```

Comment: It's not just about quotes. %s appears to convert to a string whatever you throw at it and the result is placed as is in the query. No-no. Please also see my answer.

Comment: @Giuseppe you're right, I've overlooked that the OP passes an array to `%s`.

Comment: I guess the main takeaway here is that `%s` **doesn't** quote and therefore is not really too useful for sanitizing. It does, however, escape, so it's not useless either. `@dangerous` wouldn't necessarily have to be an array. It could be string of comma separated values, e.g. `@dangerous = "1, 2, 3"`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, `%s` simply inserts into your query whatever `@dangerous.to_s` happens to be, and you are responsible for it.

For example, if @dangerous is an array of integers, then you will get an SQL error:

```
@dangerous = [1,2,3]
User.where("id IN (%s)", @dangerous)
```

will result in the following incorrect syntax:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (id IN ([1, 2, 3]))
```

whereas:

```
User.where("id IN (?)", @dangerous)
```

produces the correct query:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (id IN (1,2,3))
```

Thus, is seems to me that unless you know very, very well what you are doing, you should let the `?` operator do its job, ESPECIALLY if you do not trust the content of `@dangerous` as safe.

Comment: It seems that `%s` does escape, so it is "safe," but because it doesn't quote, it could have unexpected results, including errors. You are correct, probably best to avoid it unless one has a very good reason to do so. `Foo.where("bar = ?", @dangerous.to_s)` would accomplish the same thing, but with less worry about quoting correctly. But even this is probably unnecessary and maybe even undesirable most of the time.