# SqlServer: Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, tiny-tds

```
User.where('user_id not in (?)', CancelledUser.all.collect(&:id).join(', '))
```

Above query gives me the following error when there are no cancelled users.

> > ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [users].* FROM [userss] WHERE (user_id not in (N''''))'

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to join the `ids`, that's going to be treated as a single string literal.  Try the following:

```
User.where('user_id not in (?)', CancelledUser.all.collect(&:id))
```

**Update:**

Executing the generated query in SQL Server directly also yields the same problem.  Take a look at the answer in [Issue when retrieving records with empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946004/issue-when-retrieving-records-with-empty-array) for same problem when you have empty array.

So you could do the following to solve the issue:

```
cancelled_users = CancelledUser.all.collect(&:id)

if cancelled_users.any?
  User.where('user_id not in (?)', cancelled_users)
else
  User.all
end
```

Comment: Above doesn't return any results when there are no cancelled user

Comment: @Vimsha, I'm sure you've already resolved this issue.  I've updated my answer with a possible solution.