# Controller / ActiveRecord .where(...NOT IN...) with possible empty in set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-linux]
$ rails -v
Rails 4.2.0
$ grep DESCR /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
```

I'm trying to build and expose a subset of records to my view(s) from my controller like this:

```
@assigned_roles = @user.user_roles.select{|x| x.is_required }.map{ |ur| ur.role }

if @assigned_roles.blank?
  @optional_roles = Role.all
else
  @optional_roles = Role.where('id NOT IN (?)',@assigned_roles.map{ |r| r.id})
end
```

It works but I'm looking for something more elegant.  the .where NOT IN doesn't work as I expect when `@assigned_roles` is empty.

I have models for Role and User which `have many` of eachother through `user_roles` which bears the `t.boolean  "is_required", default: true, null: false` attribute.

Sorry I'm a total n00b so I don't know what else to include.  Much Thanks!

Comment: What were you expecting the `'NOT IN'` to do? Also, if `@assigned_roles` is empty, your code shouldn't even be getting to the `'NOT IN'` call -- you should be falling into `Role.all`. Is that not happening?

Comment: @oolong The problem is that `not in (?)` produces [nonsense](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12946338/479863) when the `?` is a placeholder for an empty array. That's why the `if @assigned_roles.blank?` is needed and the OP would prefer to not have to worry about whether or not `@assigned_roles` is empty. This is more of "how do I make this code less ugly" question than a "why doesn't this work" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that ActiveRecord doesn't know what the string `'id NOT IN (?)'` means so its replacement of the `?` placeholder is simpleminded. AR doesn't parse the SQL snippet to see how it should handle the placeholder, it just knows that there's a placeholder that it should replace with your empty array so it produces the silly looking SQL:

```
where id not in (null)
```

There's some more discussion on this over in [**Issue when retrieving records with empty array**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12946338/479863).

However, if you let ActiveRecord generate the SQL, then it can do something sensible because it *understands* what it is doing rather than blinding slinging strings around. This used to be ugly with a NOT IN but now it is easy because you can say `.where.not(...)`:

```
Role.where.not(:id => @assigned_roles.map(&:id))
```

That will produce something like this if there are `@assigned_roles`:

```
where id not in (6, 11, 23, 42)
```

and something like this if there aren't any `@assigned_roles`:

```
where 1 = 1
```

The `1 = 1` is just AR's way of building a WHERE clause that is always true (i.e. it is equivalent to `Role.all`).

Furthermore, if you can arrange for `@assigned_roles` to be a relation (i.e. `@assigned_roles = SomeModel.where(...).where(...)`) then you can get ActiveRecord to use a subquery by saying things like:

```
Role.where.not(:id => @assigned_roles.select(:role_id))
```

which will result in SQL like this:

```
where id not in (
  select role_id
  from some_models
  where ...
)
```

Keeping the query logic inside the database tends to be faster than having a bunch of chatter between the database and your Ruby code.